# Траченный молью - этимология и близкородственные слова

Tags: этимология, устаревшие-слова

Траченный молью - достаточно устаревшая фраза, хотя я всё ещё часто слышу её в обиходе. Смысл фразы понятен и не вызывает сомнений. А вот этимология и родственные слова - тут я в затруднении. Насколько близка фраза к словам "трата" и "утрата"? Почему, если буквально воспринимать фразу, слышится: "моль потратила вашу шубу"?

Comment: Это не ответ на Ваш вопрос, но комментарий à propos.  Приведённый Вами оборот действительно редкий, и его структура почти всегда неизменна: если траченный -- то именно молью.  Но из этого правила случаются исключения.  Например, "траченное временем пальтецо".  Или, как в стихотворении ИБ,  "траченный изотопом..."